# How to change a cell value in worksheet change event in vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007, export-to-excel

Actually using the following code is impossible, because we are doing a change in Worksheet_Change

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) Target.Value = "test" End Sub`

It will make an unlimited loop in the event

I must change the target only in this event

Do you have a solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: Since you are working with `Worksheet_Change`, I recommend that you see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure) post.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to prevent Excel from recognizing the change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Value = "test"
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```